# Why does my code output undefined before the reversed string?

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a string by looping through each of the words and inserting it into an empty string. The program then outputs `undefinedolleh`.

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  let final = "";
  for (let i = str.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    final += str[i];
  }
  return final;

}

console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Comment: Simply make the change `let i = str.length-1`.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays and string indexing starts at 0. So you're trying to access the position at `str.length` which doesn't exist.

Start at `str.length-1`:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  let final = "";
  for (let i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    final += str[i];
  }
  return final;

}

console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to access your string out of bounds. A string has an indice that goes from 0 to `string.length - 1`.

By the way, there is alread an function that reverse an array. So, to reverse a string, you just need to transform it to array, reverse it, and tranform back to a string

```js
console.log("hello".split("").reverse().join(""));
```